# Rails 3: Link that puts user information a specific section of to the current page, without refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails/ Javascript- so please, be gentle. (Using Rails 3, Jurby, Ruby 1.8.6)

I want to create a feature that renders information to the current page, but in a different section, when a link it clicked- like expanding details of a user, without having to go to that specific users profile.

Currently, my example will take the current user to the linked users profile, but I want the information to appear on the right side of the user feed. (I would include a screen grab, but I don't have a high enough rep). So imagine, there's a user post feed on the right side of the page that shows all global posts by each user. On the left should be an information box that is populated with a summary of the user, when their username is clicked from the associated post.

Currently, my views/pages/home.html.erb (rendering a partial called signed_in)

```
<div class="article_feed">
    <div class="article_snippet">
        <%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Got anything to say...?" %>
            </div>
                <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>   
        Communicator.. (<%= Micropost.count %>)
    </div>

    <% @microposts.each do |mp| %>
        <div class="article_snippet">               
            <%= render mp %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= will_paginate @microposts%>     
</div>  

<div class="comments_feed">
    <div class ="comments_snippet">
        <!-- this is where I want information to be displayed, once
                a link has been clicked --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

My home page controller method for this

```
  def home
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build if signed_in?
      @microposts = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page], 
              :per_page => 4).order('id DESC') if signed_in?
  end
```

Users are represented with their own model, controller and view, as are the related Microposts. At this time, all I want to display on the right side of the page is the linked user's username. The key feature of this is rendering this information as I click on each username link, at the bottom of each post. Ideally, I want to achieve this without refreshing the whole page each time.

I've spent a few days mulling this over, but my knowledge/ ability is limited at the moment- any help would be fantastic!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good task for a bit of javascript or jQuery. It looks like you're new to Rails so I'll start with the js and css inline, and you can move it to the correct locations once you understand how it works.

Start by getting the content you want in your `comments_snippet` div so the page looks like you want it to look after the link is clicked. Then change `comments_feed`:

```
<div class="comments_feed" id="comments" style="display: none;">
```

Refresh the page, and verify the div doesn't show up. Then at the top of your view add a bit of javascript to show:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show() {
        document.getElementById("comments").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Then add a link to call it:

```
<%= link_to "Show comments", "javascript:void(0)", onclick: "show()" %>
```

In a real app you might use a js library like jQuery, or css transitions, for a smooth show/hide animation. You should also keep your styles and js in separate files so they can be compiled by the Rails asset pipeline. I think that's covered later in the microposts tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! In terms of grabbing information from a users model and sticking it in the box that appears at the side. (I think my C/C++, Java background making this a bit harder to understand) but does the jquery/ javascript handle the the behaviour only, or can it also grab the information I need from the Rails model? Excellent answer though, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Glad it helps. For a simple example like this it makes sense to do everything on the server and just use js for dom manipulation. Rails does have standard approaches to pass server-side data to js on the client when you need to though, for example to set values dynamically or if there's too much data to load in one request. The "Working with Javascript" rails guide has a good overview of the options: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html